# Pass order of an element as a property

Tags: reactjs

There is a code that looks like this:

```
<div>
    <Foo order={1}/>
    <Bar order={2}/>
    ...
    <Foo order={10}/>
<div>
```

Multiple elements are located inside a div. Each of them needs to receive it's own position number. It would be a trivial task if these elements were recieved from the server and rendered dynamically via a map, but this is not the case. All these elements are actually predefined and written in a jsx file. I don't feel like passing the `order` variable to every element is the best thing to do.

I know it is possible to get element's own position in the list of its parent's children using native js. Is there a react way to achieve this?

Comment: Firstly, you can use native js in React too... As its just a js library. Secondly, you can make a HOC and inject the order prop, you don't have to add `order` prop manually.

Comment: You need to give more context... "actually predefined and written in a jsx file" What does it mean? Inserting components in an array and mapping them is an option too... `[Foo,Bar,Foo].map(...)`

Comment: It means the exaple I've posted is how the source code looks like. There is no connection to server or arrays involved.

Comment: But you decide how source can look like, why you can't map them? `[Foo,Bar,Foo].map(...)` and use order prop?

Comment: Because each of these components have their own children and a ton of other props.

Comment: Ok, it something that you should have said, I think I'll show a HOC example.

Comment: I'd appreciate it

Comment: You can use index of the element while mapping them.

Comment: There is no mapping involved though... No server side, no mappings, no arrays. Just some jsx code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a wrapper component and inject `order` prop for each of its children.

```
// Will inject order={index}
<GiveOrder>
  <Foo />
  <Bar />
  <Foo />
</GiveOrder>
```

Using `React.Children` API and [`React.cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement):

```
const GiveOrder = ({ children }) => {
  return React.Children.map(children, (child, index) =>
    React.cloneElement(child, { order: index })
  );
};
```

Full example:

```
const Foo = ({ order, title = "title" }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h3>{title}</h3>
      <span>{order}</span>
    </>
  );
};

const GiveOrder = ({ children }) => {
  return React.Children.map(children, (child, index) =>
    React.cloneElement(child, { order: index })
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <GiveOrder>
      <Foo title="foo1" />
      <Foo title="something" />
      <Foo />
    </GiveOrder>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit wizardly-ishizaka-5ulgf]